# Difference between generating a token ID and authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When a user signs up and provides a username and password and verifies their email address they can then log into their account which generates a token ID. Using that token ID in postman they can access the api. I thought this would be enough to validate the user. But what is the point of authorizers in aws?

For reference, code is similar to this: [github](https://github.com/xrlcoach/xrlcoach.github.io/blob/d6e590992df75072667523838dc9fa4f73d9b92f/lambda/login/lambda_function.py)

Am trying to understand why we need authorizers if a user can signup then login and generate the token ID and use that token ID to login. Isn't that enough to verify that the user is legimate? What does an authorizer further do?

I may be confused by authentication and authorization in aws. If I understand correctly, authorization just means the user knows the username/password and authentication is like an artifact like a cookie to determines that the username/password is coming from the original person who created that username/password?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the authorizer on apigateway, then they are used to check if your token is valid. An authorizer checks your token against the resource, eg cognito user pool and make sure it belongs to that pool and isn't expired. If you don't have an authorizer and aren't verifying or using the token in your code at all then any person can pass a string in authorization header for API call and the call will go through.